# how to move from my MyAcctivity.java (login page) to HomeActivity.java (home page) with a click of button- INTELLIJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

It doesnt have any errors ..when i run on my emulator it **UNFORTUNATELY STOPS**
i am trying to make my button when i click it takes me to the next page....kindly help!
Here is codes for MyActivity.java

```
package com.example.INIKO_EVENTS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
     Button login;
     Button sign_up;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button15);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                MyActivity.this.
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        sign_up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
        sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class);
                MyActivity.this.
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

and heres my HomeActivity.java - it has buttons linking to other pages

```
package com.example.INIKO_EVENTS;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
/**
 * Created by eddie kamau on 2/14/14.
 */
Button button2;
Button button3;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toEventButton);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,EventActivity.class);
                HomeActivity.this.
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.manage_your_guestButton2);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,GuestActivity.class);
                HomeActivity.this.
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        }
    }
```

**main.xml**

```
    <Button
            android:layout_width="141dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/login"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:id="@+id/Button15"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="121dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_up"
            android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:maxWidth="600dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**home.xml**

```
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_your_event"
            android:id="@+id/toEventButton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/manage_your_event"
            android:id="@+id/manage_your_guestButton2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:clickable="true"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/your_events"
            android:id="@+id/your_eventsButton3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:clickable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your log cat out put and remove this code and try `MyActivity.this.`

Comment: have you defined these activities in manifest?

Comment: i use genymotion so it doesnt show the logcat

Comment: @Swarna kindly show me how to define them in manifest

Comment: @user3332215 did you try this???

Comment: <activity android:name="com.example.INIKO_EVENTS.HomeActivity" </activity>

Comment: yes i have tried still the same...app stops when i click any button

Answer (score 0):

try this

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button login;
 Button sign_up;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    sign_up=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
```

}

homeactivity.java

```
 public class HomeActivity  extends Activity{
Button button2;
Button button3;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,EventActivity.class);
                HomeActivity.this.
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,GuestActivity.class);
                HomeActivity.this.
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        }
    }
```

manifest.xml
define all this class in mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.target"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.target.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.target.EventActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.target.GuestActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.target.HomeActivity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: in...."com.example.target.EventActivity" the target part do i replace with INIKO_EVENTS since in my package is package com.example.INIKO_EVENTS;

Comment: com.example.INIKO_EVENTS.EventActivity

Comment: it doesnt have any red error..but i hac my logcat now...though its long

Comment: then what is the problem??